# How Display SetText Value on UI after reading a file line by line in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface

I am using BufferedReader to read from a text file line by line and want to display the line simultaneously on the Android UI.

I have tried to solve the problem using various delays, but it did not solve my problem.

```
 BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                Log.e("File path",filePath);
                parsedByteStream = reader.readLine();
                while (parsedByteStream != null) {
                    Log.i("Line",parsedByteStream);
                    fileDataStream[lineNo] = parsedByteStream;
                    lineNo++;
                    parsedByteStream = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<lineNo;i++) {
                myTextView.setText(fileDataStream[i]);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

On the Android UI I am only getting the last line on the UI as the set text value.

Comment: Concat the string using StringBuilder and then use setText

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` on the TextView

```
myTextView.append(fileDataStream[i]);
```

Remove this

```
try {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: May also need to add line breaks - depends on the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can StringBuilder for text as:

```
BufferedReader reader;
StringBuilder sb;
            try {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                Log.e("File path",filePath);
                parsedByteStream = reader.readLine();
                while (parsedByteStream != null) {
                    Log.i("Line",parsedByteStream);
                    fileDataStream[lineNo] = parsedByteStream;
                    lineNo++;
                    parsedByteStream = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<lineNo;i++) {
                 sb.append(""+fileDataStream[i]);

                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    myTextView.setText(""+sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler for delayed instead of TimeUnit class.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Add your code here 
        }
    }, 3000);
```